# rxjs can manual subscription handling be replaced with switchmap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have a service to manage logged in user. I have a second service that provides datasource for logged-in user's list items. Both services are singletons and (possibly) live longer than one users login.

I have this pattern reoccurring a lot:

```
this._loggedInUserService.loggedInUserObservable.subscribe(loggedInUser: User => {

  // Remove old subscription
  if (this._subscription) {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe()
    this._subscription = null
  }

  if (loggedInUser) {
    this._subscription = this._otherService.getUserSpecificObservable(loggedInUser).subscribe(...)
  }

})
```

Now that I have read a bit about switchMap, is the following functionally equal with the code above? Is the subscription correctly ended if the user changes?

```
this._loggedInUserService.loggedInUserObservable.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      return this._otherService.getUserSpecificObservable(loggedInUser)
    } else {
      // What to return here?
    }
  })
).subscribe(...)
```

Also, what should I return in the else? I don't need the subscription to work at all in that case, so is it safe just to return null or undefined? Or should I return empty Observable (import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs')? (The code in subscribe does not need to be run if there is no active user.)

Comment: Yes, you can return just `empty()`. `switchMap` will unsubscribe from any inner Observable automatically. If you want to be sure you can use `finalize()` like `.getUserSpecificObservable(loggedInUser).pipe(finalize(() => console.log('unsubed')))`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you aren't interested in values that are not defined, you can just filter them out before calling the second service:

```
this._loggedInUserService.loggedInUserObservable.pipe(
  filter(user => !!user),
  switchMap(user => this._otherService.getUserSpecificObservable(user))
).subscribe(...)
```

You can also see the principial idea in action here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-p75oku